# Python 3.5 - Create folder with subfolder under Windows

Tags: python, windows, path

Is there some elegant way how to create Windows path as follows.

```
home_dir = ('C:\First\Second\Third')        
if not os.path.exists(home_dir):
    os.mkdir(home_dir)
    print("Home directory %s was created." %home_dir)
```

I am able to create in single steps "C:\First" then "Second" etc ...

With this code I am getting:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\First\Second\Third'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the existence of a directory path with [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir):

> Return True if path is an existing directory.

```
os.path.isdir("C:\First\Second\Third")
```

This will avoid the FileNotFoundError.

Then create the dirs. It looks like so:

```
home_dir = ('C:\First\Second\Third')        
if not os.path.isdir(home_dir):
    os.makedirs(home_dir)
    print("Home directory %s was created." %home_dir)
```

Comment: For Python 3.2+ you can also use `os.makedirs(home_dir, exist_ok=True)`. This creates all directories in the path, if necessary, and won't raise `FileExistsError` if the leaf directory already exists.

Answer (score 3):

To create a folder with subfolders use:

```
os.makedirs(home_dir)
```

Comment: I tried to use os.makidirs before and was getting exactly the same error. 
I see now that the problem I had was somehow corrupted file with my code. At the momement when I try to execute I am getting (unicode error) cant decode bytes.
Anyway, creating New File resolved the problem and this works as expected.

Thank you for quick response.

Comment: @Michal if you specifyed a path like `c:\dir1\dirs2` and if `dir1` does not exist it will fail (`The specified path was not found`)